# Google Cloud Compute Python Library package naming confusion

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

In the Google Compute Python library we seem to have 2 packages - screenshot
[image: GCP Python Client GitHub].

When importing the various modules should we refer to `compute` or `compute_v1`? It seems `compute` internally refers to `compute_v1`? Why is this structure introduced and what would be the right/consistent way to import the modules? Most of the examples on internet and GCP documentation use `compute_v1`.

e.g.

```py
from google.cloud import compute_v1

OR

from google.cloud import compute
```

Comment: Refer to the documentation. `compute_v1` is the current version that replaced `compute`. https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest I realize this is confusing, but it sometimes happens as vendors rapidly develop their SDKs, libraries, and tools.

Comment: To add to the confusion, the correct library installation command is `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-compute`.

Comment: @JohnHanley: I am not able to find on the link where it says that the compute_v1 is the current version that replaced compute. Can you share a screenshot of it? I agree this is really confusing, it would probably make sense to version the package with semantic versioning and not have any version suffixes in the package level which I believe google adheres to.. not sure i understand the design philosophy behind this case. when google releases v2 of the google-cloud-compute package, will it rename compute_v1 to compute_v2 as well? that would be a bigger refactor that not many would like.

Comment: Go to the changelog to see the version history: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/changelog